# graphics and indicators for drag-n-drop

Tags: drag-n-drop

I'm looking for a good indicators to tell a user something is draggable, and to some extent, to tell the user (once they are dragging), that they can drop something "here".

What have you used as indicators for these action? I'm looking for a little more than "make the cursor="move" when they mouse over it. I'm also thinking more along the lines of persistent, not things that only show on mouse over. In a sense the indicator must be strong yet subtle.

Thoughts?